# ajaxForm submission happens twice

Tags: spring-mvc, ajaxform

//js

```
$("#saveMerchantsForm").ajaxForm({
                success : function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            }).submit();
```

//html

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/manager/saveMerchant}" th:object="${merchantModal}" id="saveMerchantsForm" method="POST">

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
<input class="clear" th:field="*{merchantFname}" id="merchantFname" type="text"/>
<label class="merchantFname clear" style="width: 100%;" for="merchantFname">Merchant First Name</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
<input class="clear" id="merchantMname" th:field="*{merchantMname}" type="text"/>
<label class="merchantMname clear" style="width: 100%;"  for="merchantMname">Merchant Middle Name</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

while i go for submission, it submit the form twice, how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add a unbind before your .ajaxForm function like this:

```
$("#saveMerchantsForm").unbind('ajaxForm');
$("#saveMerchantsForm").ajaxForm({
            success : function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        }).submit();
```

Or you could use a one like this:

```
$("#saveMerchantsForm").one('ajaxForm');
$("#saveMerchantsForm").ajaxForm({
            success : function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        }).submit();
```

one means that this function will only run once per element.

unbind removes the previously binded element.

That at least solves my problem with functions firing multiple times